# Error on retrieve image from assets

Tags: android, bitmap, assets, decoder

I need to retrieve an image from the assets folder and I need to use a Bitmap to handle the image. The name of the file is image.jpg. This is the code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AssetManager manager = getAssets();

        try {
            InputStream is = manager.open("image.jpg");
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(img);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But I can't understand why the app crashes. This is the error log.

```
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567): Process: com.example.instacut, PID: 10567
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.instacut/com.example.instacut.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5116)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at com.example.instacut.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
06-28 18:17:16.488: E/AndroidRuntime(10567):    ... 12 more
```

I'm following a site on internet for this and it's exactly the same. I really don't understand what's wrong here.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving a Null Pointer error because `imageView` is actually a `null` object.

First of all, there is an error in the code you posted:

```
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView);
   this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
```

Should be:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
```

remove the first semicolon. If this wasn't the problem, then `imageView` is set to `null` because it's not properly associating with as resource within you're `activity_main.xml` file. Make sure that you have an `ImageView` declared with `android:id="@+id/ImageView1"` declared within `activity_main.xml` and not somewhere else. If that doesn't help, post the file and we will help you spot the error.

In the future, if you ask an Android question, be sure to include any relevant xml/resource files in your post.

Comment: I checked everything and all seems to be good.
In the fragment_main.xml I wrote (in an ImageView): android:id="@+id/ImageView1"

Comment: If everything is working now, please accept an answer. If not, you'll have to post your xml file.

Comment: I was working on the frament_main.xml file, when I should have worked on the activity_main.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Can you please point out which line is line number 41 in MainActivity.Java because its easier to spot the error if we know at which point it throws the NullPointerException.

Comment: It's imageView.setImageBitmap(img);